# HTML POST Request doesn't send all the data

Tags: html, node.js, express

I am using Node.js + Express.js to build a very basic search engine for a Library database. My HTML has a POST form that sends either a title or keyword to the app in order to query a MySQL database for the book/books. The search by title is working fine but the keyword is giving me a hard time. See below.

**HTML**

```
<form id="searchForm" action="" method="post">

        <select class="form-control" id="searchType">
            <option class="" value="0">Search by title</option>
            <option class="" value="1">Search by keyword</option>
        </select>

        <select class="form-control" id="titles" name="titles">
            <% for (var title in titles) {;%>

            <option class=""><%=titles[title].TITLE%></option>

            <% }; %>
        </select>

        <textarea class="form-control" name="keyword" contenteditable="false" id="keyword" placeholder="Enter keyword here..."></textarea> <!-- placeholder is only supported in a few browesers
                                                                                                                                           (Firefox 3.7+, Chrome, Safari, IE 10). Could use 
                                                                                                                                           jQuery but ah-->
        <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Search"></input>
    </form> <!-- /searchForm -->
```

**Express code**

```
app.post('/getBooksByTitle', function (req, res) {
    connection.getConnection(function(err, tempCon) {
        if (err) {
            tempCon.release();
            console.log('ERROR IN SQL CONNECTION!');
        }
        else {
            console.log('CONNECTED TO SQL');
            tempCon.query('SELECT * FROM BOOKS WHERE TITLE=?', req.body.titles, function(err, rows) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log('BAD QUERY');
                }
                else {
                    console.log(req.body.titles);
                    res.json(rows);
                }
                tempCon.release();
            });
        }
    });
});
app.post('/getBooksByKeyword', function (req, res) {
    connection.getConnection(function(err, tempCon) {
        if (err) {
            tempCon.release();
            console.log('ERROR IN SQL CONNECTION!');
        }
        else {
            console.log('CONNECTED TO SQL');
            tempCon.query('SELECT * FROM BOOKS WHERE (AUTHOR LIKE ? || TITLE LIKE ? || GENRE LIKE ? || DESCRIPTION LIKE ?)', '%' + req.body.keyword + '%', function(err, rows) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log('BAD QUERY');
                    console.log(req.body);
                }
                else {
                    res.json(rows);
                    console.log(req.body.keyword);
                }
                tempCon.release();
            });
        }
    });
});
```

I am pulling the form data to node with `req.body.(field_name)` but it doesn't seem to gather the text box. If I `console.log(req.body)` I see only the title field. Where have I messed up?

EDIT: The jQuery script that handles the action and some animations.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    toggleFields(); //call this first so we start out with the correct visibility depending on the selected form values
    //this will call our toggleFields function every time the selection value of our searchType field changes
    $("#searchType").change(function () {
        toggleFields();
    });

});
//this toggles the visibility of our input fields depending on the current selected value of the searchType field.
//also it toggles the action of the submit form to the appropriete post call.
function toggleFields() {
    if ($("#searchType").val() == 0) {
        $("#searchForm").attr('action', '/getBooksByTitle');
        $("#titles").slideDown();
        $("#keyword").slideUp();
    }
    else {
        $("#searchForm").attr('action', '/getBooksByKeyword');
        $("#titles").slideUp();
        $("#keyword").slideDown();
    }
}
```

Comment: Check the devtools network tab, is the data sent?

Comment: @Jeff When checking the Net tab in firebug only the title field appears to be sent.

Comment: did you want your html to post data to both of this routes?!

Comment: @Elyas74 The html posts to only one route at a time. The action attribute is handled by a Jquery script based on the `searchType` value.

Comment: @Akaitenshi can you post the actual html of "form" that is rendered in the browser? Also the javascript that you use to call this route "getBooksByKeyword".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help you tried to provide. I fixed the problem by changing the `<textarea>` field to an `<input>` field. Now the post sends both my title and keyword back to the server.